# Flutter/Dart Android App NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I got a quick question about a flutter/dart app I am making throwing this certain error.

It has something to do with my showadddialog class. When I press the flatbutton with the text "save" in _showAddDialog() it works fine but my app crashes if I tap out of the alert dialog window without entering anything or if I press the flatbutton named "delete", and both actions give the same error. however, when I restart I can see that the delete button still worked to delete the events from the shared preferences, it just crashed afterward. What could be causing this in my code? Idk where it could be calling a map on null...

Screenshot reference: https://gyazo.com/f894ae742ea50cd714026b1bbe753678

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#42494], _InheritedTheme], state: _HomePageState#acde6):
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Widget>(Closure: (dynamic) => ListTile)

The relevant error-causing widget was
    HomePage 
package:hello_world/main.dart:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _HomePageState.build 
package:hello_world/main.dart:135
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4334
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4223
#4      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Code here:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Calendar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  CalendarController _controller;
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  List<dynamic> _selectedEvents;
  TextEditingController _eventController;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _eventController = TextEditingController();
    _events = {};
    _selectedEvents = [];
    initPrefs();
  }

  initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _events = Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>.from(
        decodeMap(json.decode(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}"))
      );
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> encodeMap(Map<DateTime, dynamic> map) {
    Map<String, dynamic> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[key.toString()] = map[key];
    });
    return newMap;
  }

  Map<DateTime, dynamic> decodeMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    Map<DateTime, dynamic> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[DateTime.parse(key)] = map[key];
    });
    return newMap;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Calendar'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(
              events: _events,
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                canEventMarkersOverflow: true,
                todayColor: Colors.orange,
                selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                todayStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.white
                )
              ),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                centerHeaderTitle: true,
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,
              ),
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
              onDaySelected: (date, events) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedEvents = events;
                });
              },
              builders: CalendarBuilders(
                selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    date.day.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                ),
                todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    date.day.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                ),
              ),
              calendarController: _controller,
            ),

            ..._selectedEvents.map((event) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(event),
                )),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: _showAddDialog,
      ),
    );
  }

  _showAddDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: TextField(
                controller: _eventController,
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Save"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) return;
                    if (_events[_controller.selectedDay] != null) {
                      _events[_controller.selectedDay].add(_eventController.text);
                    } else {
                      _events[_controller.selectedDay] = [
                        _eventController.text
                      ];
                    }
                    prefs.setString("events", json.encode(encodeMap(_events)));
                    _eventController.clear();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Delete Events"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _events.remove(_controller.selectedDay);
                      prefs.setString("events", json.encode(encodeMap(_events)));
                      _eventController.clear();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                );
                  }
                )
              ],
        )
      );
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = _events[_controller.selectedDay];
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code, and handled delete event null exception as per below.
Change your last setState code with below:

```
setState(() {
   _selectedEvents = _events[_controller.selectedDay] ?? [];
});
```

**Conclusion:**
_selectedEvents null value can be handled by `?? []` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this was the fix I was looking for!